# Webkit ignores onwebkitspeechchange callback

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition

Using speech recognition available in Google Chrome version 11 and jquery

```
<input type="text"  id="txtAns" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech"  onwebkitspeechchange="onChange()"  />
```

I put the onChange() function in a js jquery file that I referenced in the head of my web page

After a successful speech recognition, the onChange function should be called but it is not. If I create a javascript function on the page called onChange() it is called. Any reasons why the jquery version is not being called?

Comment: you might want to post the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

I think you put the script on the head section of the dom. Try putting the script on the bottom, also you could try adding document ready if you want to include it on the head.

```
<input id="queryField" type="text" x-webkit-speech>
```

Javascript

---

```
<script>
var field = document.querySelector('#queryField');
field.onwebkitspeechchange = function(e) {
  console.log("You have spoken");
};
</script>
```

jQuery

---

```
<script>
  $('#queryField').bind('webkitspeechchange', function() {
    console.log("You have spoken");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Very very helpful answer. I can confirm that second solution using `bind` definitely works.